# how to mask password in bat

Tags: batch-file, passwords, command

I have this code snippet from a Stack Overflow question about masking input in a batch script.

```
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
echo %password%
```

---

And here is my script.

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
title Folder Locker
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST Locker goto MDLOCKER
:CONFIRM
echo Are you sure u want to Lock the folder(Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM
:LOCK
ren Locker "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto End
:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to Unlock folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%==Your-Password-Here goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Locker
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End
:FAIL
echo Invalid password
goto end
:MDLOCKER
md Locker
echo Locker created successfully
goto End
:End
```

Now, I want to implement the code snippet I showed earlier into my own script, where should I put the snippet into the script? Should I remove some code or not?

Comment: You just replace `set /p pass` with it. You have to change either %pass% to %password% in the second script or %password% to %pass% in the first one. Do keep in mind that it's still in plain text when you check it with `if`. You can at least get *some* additional security if you echo the password into a file, generate the hash of that file and compare the hash (after which you delete the file).

Comment: hi and thx for answer my question
my problem got solved
but in ur answer i didnt underestand this part :

Do keep in mind that it's still in plain text when you check it with if. You can at least get some additional security if you echo the password into a file, generate the hash of that file and compare the hash (after which you delete the file)

pss: im not a programmer so if u can say it very easy

thx

Comment: Did you use the same method to check if the password is correct? Does your code contain `if %password%==PlainPassword` somewhere? Because anyone can just open the script with notepad and see the password. An example for generating a hash would be `certutil -hashfile TempPassword.txt SHA256` and comparing the output of that (for example `if %password%==f0f5a997d1989792669861758ace216ebf1b48587376b7cc5e6b59cc8180cda3`) would at least make it slightly harder for someone else who doesn't know batch.